# How do add classes to elements and change page title through AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So, I've recently stumbled upon some amazing Framework, **AngularJS**.

I really like it, and it seems to be the perfect fit for me, therefore, I need a few things before I can move forward.

I would like to be able to change the page title of the page, based on

*(a)* The page URL, and/or

*(b)* Data received, such as a form being submitted, rather than showing an alert, the title of the page will change, and the page contents may change

Also, I'm looking to add classes to the menu links based on what the current page is. Therefore, if the current page is Home, I want to add a class to the `<li>` element of "Home", and not others, and when on "About", the `<li>` element for that page should have the active class for that nav item.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps show some code of what you've already done.  JSFiddle would help a lot to get an answer for you.

Comment: AFAIK _AngularJS_ doesn't prevent you writing _VanillaJS_.

Comment: The first requirement can be solved by utilizing $routeParams and the second by ngClass.  These pieces of angular are pretty well documented, check them out.

Comment: @mortalapeman why don't you put in some some code and help him and other.

Comment: What Paul said. People get so used to shortcuts with different libraries *cough* jquery *cough* they forget to use Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first requirement can be solved by utilizing [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeParams) and the second by [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass).

Here is a quick [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/APycqu?p=preview) to get you started:

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { template: '<p>Home page<p>'})
        .when('/:title', { template: '<p>Page for {{ name }}</p>', controller: 'MainCtrl'})
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, prev) {
        $scope.name = $routeParams.title || 'World';
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <h2> Hello {{ name }}!</h2>
      <ul class="nav-bar">
        <li ng-class="name"><a href="#/Bob">Bob</a></li>
        <li ng-class="name"><a href="#/Harry">Harry</a></li>
        <li ng-class="name"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.nav-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-bar li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px;
}

.Bob {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Harry {
  background-color: orange;
}
```